# Nodejs + express regexp and params

Tags: node.js, regex, express, routes

I want to create a route, where the param matters only. I tried like this but have not worked:

```
..
    router.get('^.*?/:name', (req, res) => {
..
```

Could you help me a bit with this please? :)

Comment: Do you mean match all the routes ends with a name param?

Comment: i think it is not good idea to implement as every request with path `abc/yxz` will go here unless post request . what I mean is this route will handle all the request which is having `..../....` . so it will not be efficient at all

Answer (score 1):

```
'^.*?/:name'
```

dot is not needed in express's router.

```
'^*/:name'
```

will work!